# Help with Workflow for an Enterprise GeoDatabase Management

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3

[This is a cross post from ESRI's forum--not even getting many views there. Apologies for the duplicate.]

Please see this for reference: http://img42.com/YA1Qo

I have been tasked with creating an ESRI Javascript API application; but I could also have access to ASP.NET and/or php environments if needed. The attached file show a data model I have been working on. It shows only a few fields. It is for a university. Briefly, here is what the model describes: The 'Buildings' table will have all the buildings on campus. The 'RoomData' table will have all Rooms from all Buildings. The 'FloorPlans' table will have all Floor Plans for every Floor of every Building. Let's forget the Insurance table for now.

The database will be SQL Server 2012. The Server OS will be Windows 2012. ESRI's ArcGIS for Server 10.3 will be the GIS Server.

The challenge before me is to enable non-technical staff to Add a building to the enterprise geodatabase and then add individual Rooms for that Building, and Floor Plans for that Buildings for each Floor of that Building.

Solution 1: I foresee a web-based solution as better: A 'wizard' which would guide the users through adding data through online forms. Not a problem. But the problem is Spatial data. Specifically, how can each Building's polygon be made into the Building's table in a web interface? The users could have an ArcMap document where they could draw the Polygon but how could that be sent to the data's correct field? Maybe some python script?

Solution 2: ArcMap based solution: There can be two MXDs/Building. Each MXD can have all the Rooms (or Floor Plans) data for a specific building. So these two MXDs would cover all the required data for a Building. There can also be an additional field called 'Building_ID' with hard-coded value for a Building (which would exist in another table in the geodatabase). This is the current solution in a 'Pilot' project and kind of works: Each of the two MXDs get Published to the GIS Server--through an interface with SQL Server (ArcSDE). However, this is not a true relational database.

Let me add that I may be completely off or maybe over-complicating matters. I thought a wizard based approach would be better but am more than willing to listen to other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood but:

If you have an Enterprise GDB for an university, you probably have access to privileges of an ArcGIS Organizational account. Can you create 3 featureclass services that allows users to log into the ArcGIS Online and edit? Then you just have to reconcile the edits. I haven't ran into a situation that needed edits to 3 featureclasses.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this would fit our scenario, as my my Question above. Anyway, I am well on my way into setting up per my own Answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the 'workflow' figured out--this is like the 'Solution 1'

1) Users would author in ArcMap in .MXD files

2) Users would then export to .JSON from .MXDs

3) In a web page, users would select a Building and then they would be prompted to upload the .JSON file for the appropriate Building

4) An ASP.NET application would parse the JSON file and do the Inserts in a 'RoomData' table in such a way that Building's ID from the Buildings table would be part of each data row.

All of these steps have been successfully tested in a local environment; for #4, there is currently a C# Console application which will be converted to an ASP.NET application soon.

I hope this helps someone.